# Web application and hardware interaction

Tags: hardware-interface

First off, let me apologize if this has been asked already, but I can’t seem to locate a solid answer.

Is there any web application language or related process that will allow a web app to interact with the local PC hardware? I am trying to see if there is a way to have a web page interface with a local scanner device to capture, write file, and upload the images. I read something about Silverlight being able to read from USB keys, but that is the extent of what I have found.

Any thoughts on this or ideas of places to look for more information would be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want the application to interact with the machine that is running the browser, then, no, that would be a serious security hole.

You can use ActiveX controls, or maybe SilverLight to create applications that have more access to the client machine.

You might also be better off creating a ClickOnce application that runs on the users system and uploads the data to your web server.

BTW, you seem to be assuming that the user is running on a PC. What if they'e using a Linux workstation, or a Macintosh?

Comment: Does linux play nice at all with a scanner anyways?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John. I appreciate you sharing your thoughts. I do agree that it could potentially be a security problem, but I was thinking that maybe some solution existed to safely get past this. Good point on the platform statement, I hadn't given that much thought to cross platform compatibility yet.

Comment: @Jeremy: what I meant is that if the browser allowed web sites to access local hardware, then that would be a security bug in the browser. SilverLight doesn't have that problem as much, as it runs in a restricted, but more open, sandbox. ActiveX can do anything it wants to, but users and admins have to permit it. Of course, it can also crash the user's machine, delete all their files, etc.